# Problems with UIScrollViews in a picture gallery

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, gallery, gestures

I'm implementing a gallery that has UIScrollViews inside a main UIScrollView.
I'm trying to change next page while is the zoom in.
But the first try the scroll doesn't move, until the second time that the image swipes correctly.

I think that UIGestures would be a possible way, but in that case, I would have to implement all the automatic effects that UIScrollView automatically do.

Is there an easy possibility to change to next picture?
If I only could get the displacement of the finger in scrollViewDidScroll method, i would do it perfectly.

Comment: can u reformulate this:  "I'm trying to change next page while is the zoom in. But the first try the scroll doesn't move, until the second time that the image swipes correctly." I have no clue what u are talking about it here...

Comment: As a gallery, you would change the pictures, even the images is zoomed. When I do the swipe gesture the first time, the magnet effect returns the image to the edge of picture. The second time you  makes the gesture, the main UIScrollView catches the event, and the image moves to the next one on the gallery.